# Getting Carbon Fields value inside of namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, carbon-fields

How can you access the `carbon_get_post_meta` function from within a namespace?

```php
namespace SeoThemes\GenesisStarterTheme\Functions;

if ( function_exists( 'carbon_get_post_meta' ) ):
    echo 'true';
else:
    echo 'false';
endif;
```

This returns false currently, but if I do the same thing inside of page.php it returns true.

I know that I'll have to fix the namespace issue, I just don't know how... I thought if I add `\` first then it'd go to the root namespace but it still returns false.

i.e. `\carbon_get_post_meta`

Can anyone help?